# Python string.title() issue with German umlauts

Tags: python, string, utf-8, diacritics

I got a strange behavior of the Python string.title() function if the string contains German umlauts (üöä). Then, not only the first character of the string is capitalized, but as well the character following the umlaut.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
a = "müller"
print a.title()
# this returns >MüLler< , not >Müller< as expected
```

Tried to fix by setting locale to German UTF-8 charset, but no success:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.UTF-8')
a="müller"
print a.title()
# same value >MüLler<
```

Any ideas to prevent the capitalization after the umlaut?
My Python version is 2.6.6 on debian linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Decode* your string to Unicode, then use `unicode.title()`:

```
>>> a = "müller"
>>> a.decode('utf8').title()
u'M\xfcller'
>>> print a.decode('utf8').title()
Müller
```

You can always encode to UTF-8 again later on.

Comment: @doublep: where you can still reproduce the same issue if you use `bytes` instead of `str`, which is essentially what is going on here.

Comment: Yes, but in Python 3 string literals are already of type that was `unicode` before, so you don't need to decode.

Comment: @doublep: sure, but don't assume that the real problem actually involves string literals.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for your quick answer!